# How to calculate result of a boolean table?

Tags: boolean, calculation

I have 2 boolean values, `bool_a` and `bool_b`. I also have a third boolean `result`, which is dependent on the values of `bool_a` and `bool_b`, see the following table:

|  | **`bool_b = True`** | **`bool_b = False`** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **`bool_a = True`** | True | False |
| **`bool_a = False`** | False | True |

I can get the result of `result` easily by multiplying the booleans `result = bool_a * bool_b`, except when `bool_a` and `bool_b` are both False. What is the easiest way of calculating the value of `result` based on the boolean values?